# Posting data into JSON format

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, json

I am working on iPhone application. Here I am trying to post my data with following code :

```
    NSDictionary *contactData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:score] ,@"score",  
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:game_id] ,@"game_id",  
                             game_version ,@"game_version",  
                             platform ,@"platform",  
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:timestamp] ,@"timestamp",  
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:elapsed_time] ,@"elapsed_time",
                             hash ,@"hash",
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:level_reached] ,@"level_reached",
                             verification ,@"verification",
                             nil];
[request1 addPostValue:contactData forKey:@"plays[]"];
```

And I want to generate following format :

```
Array
(
   [plays] => Array
       (
           [0] => Array
                       (
                        [score] = 513956
                       [game_id] = 1
                         [game_version] = 1.0
                 [platform] = Web
                   [timestamp] = 1313146039
                       [elapsed_time] = 400
                       [hash] = 61e51000143566bfddjfhdeur88cb7b2ad
                 [level_reached] = 5
                   [verification] = e56a35341c7854dref82ad678cb11593
                   )
   )
   [module] => play
   [action] => save
)
```

How it can be implemented where I have to make changes or where I am making mistakes.
Please help me. I am stuck on that.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's the output of PHP's `print_r`.

Comment: Please help me how to convert it into valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you return **valid** JSON from your (?) web service, you can use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to convert from and to JSON.

PHP has `json_encode` and `json_decode` for this purpose. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).